# parse-server-example: Unable to ensure uniqueness for usernames: MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, parsing

I am following the video tutorial [Your First Parse Server App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o522ovITvW4&t=486s). When I try to run `npm start`, I get the error Unable to ensure uniqueness for usernames:

```
MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

What do I do I'm not sure I've seen other of the same question that have been answered but I don't understand the solution.

Comment: Plese give us more information. `npm start` runs the start script or a node server (depending on you script, but I have no way of knowing where the bug occured.

Comment: sorry but what exact info do you need its just that I'm new to this and don't know what to provide

Comment: Take a look at Stackoverflow's guidlines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What I would like is to see the actual code.  Are you using a framework? If so, which one.

Comment: i am basically following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o522ovITvW4&t=486s everything up until he starts nam start is what I'm up to

Comment: There is a thread on the parse-server example github https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example/issues/258. I have no experiance with parse server, but from what I can tell, you have to make sure you are running MongoDB and you can access the db.

Comment: how exactly would i do this?

Comment: nvm i connected to mongo ty for the help :)

Comment: sure how would we do that?